# Cannot use IntelliTrace to collect the call information because of System.AccessViolationException

Tags: visual-studio, intellitrace

Recently, I've installed VS 2015 RC. It uses IntelliTrace in the version 14. Since then I've had a problem with earlier versions of IntelliTrace.

The problem occurs when I try to collect the call information (if I want to collect only diagnostic events there is no problem). Regardless, if I use the Standalone Collector or VS I'm receiving the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write
protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Re-installation of VS 2015 didn't help. In the event log I see the following list of events (starting from the earliest):

```
TraceLog Profiler component initialized successfully, process Example.exe

.NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.0 - The profiler was loaded successfully.             
Profiler CLSID: '{f1260058-1a1f-4738-8be2-0bf9d3a64219}'.  Process ID
(decimal): 7196.  Message ID: [0x2507].

TraceLog Profiler in process Example.exe experienced an internal failure.    
The accuracy of the collected trace may be affected.

Application: Example.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:

Faulting application name: Example.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4ecfa3a5
Faulting module name: Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Profiler.11.0.0.SC.dll, version: 11.0.50522.1, time stamp: 0x4fbadafb
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000040d24
Faulting process id: 0x1c1c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0ad8432baa357
Faulting application path: C:\Temp\Example.exe
Faulting module path: C:\StandaloneCollector\Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Profiler.11.0.0.SC.dll
Report Id: 709fb3dd-1977-11e5-9c79-240a644a5a8d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

At the beginning everything is ok but then something goes wrong. Example.exe is a console application.

Before VS 2015 RC I had a beta version installed and I didn't spot any problems like that.

I could use IntelliTrace for VS 2015 RC but I'd like to know why other versions don't work. There is probably some conflict. I also wonder why the Standalone Collector was affected. I was sure that it is independent from VS binaries.

Did you experience something similar? Any ideas?

***** EDIT *****

It looks like that I wasn't clear enough. IntelliTrace distributed with VS 2015 (version 14) works correctly. However, earlier versions of IntelliTrace (version 11 and 12) don't work. They stopped working after installing VS 2015 RC.

Comment: Use connect.microsoft.com to report bugs in the RC edition.

Comment: I suppose you installed the standalone collector from online http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44909. Am I reading it right that you have both the old standalone collector and the Visual Studio 2015 IntelliTrace on the same box?

Comment: More precisely, I have VS 2012, 2013, 2015 and corresponding standalone collectors on the same machine. As to standalone collectors, I actually didn't install them. I simply downloaded archives and unpacked them.

Comment: As Hans Passant suggested I asked a question on Microsoft Connect. Here is a link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1463958/cannot-use-intellitrace-to-collect-the-call-information-because-of-system-accessviolationexception

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for raising the issue.
If you are running an old version of IntelliTrace standalone collector with Visual Studio 2015 installed, this is likely a known issue. The problem is .Net 4.6 will be installed with VS 2015, the old IntelliTrace code will have problem work with the latest version of .Net. The solution I want to suggest would be upgrading your standalone collector to the latest version.
Please let me know if you are still seeing the issue with latest standalone collector and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pick up a copy of the newest standalone collector from your drop of Visual Studio. It can be found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\14.0.0\IntelliTraceCollection.cab

Try using that cab. The problem may have been fixed there.